# Clarification on reviews

Tags: discussion, review, comments

Over the last week I've done a number of reviews of new user first posts and late answers.  I used as guidance, "Help your fellow members learn to use the site".  With that in mind, I created lengthy comments explaining nicely why many of the posts weren't appropriate or how to post properly.  Several times I was curious whether that input had any result.  I went back to the reviews list to find the posts and they were missing.  It finally occurred to me that the posts were deleted and the comments and record of review went with them.

The reviews don't take trivial time and I suspect the typical review doesn't entail writing a lengthy comment to explain things, so I'm probably putting in more effort than necessary.  Clearly, many of these posts should be deleted.  However, how will these "fellow members" learn what's appropriate or how to improve if the feedback is deleted before they have a chance to read it?

I'm left with the impression that any feedback on posts that are likely to be deleted is a waste of time, and that is the majority of "no action needed" reviews.  Which means most feedback on posts that would benefit from feedback is a waste.  The review process helps to keep the quality of the site up, but it looks like the two objectives are at cross purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Users will get a notification in the global inbox even if the question or answer gets deleted, so your work isn't completely wasted. They also still have a opportunity (even if brief) to see your comment before it is deleted. In addition, because users can always see their own deleted answers, comments to deleted answers will remain visible to them. (However, 10K is needed to view deleted questions.)

I don't think any major changes should be made to what you're doing. Even if the user may not have a chance to see your full comment, you've still done your best to get the point across.

In any case, given the level of activity you've shown over the last few weeks, you are well on your way to becoming a ♦moderator. Keep it up.